# When to use an enumerated in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I am creating a WPF application and trying to assign a Priority Level to different objects of the same class. For that I use the following enumerated type:

```
public enum PriorityLevel 
{
    LEVEL1 = 1,
    LEVEL2 = 2,
    LEVEL3 = 3
}
```

Basically, based on the criteria I'm using, objects PLevel property (of type PriorityLevel) is set to some LEVEL of those defined in the enum.

My problem is when I show that property in the interface (with a binding in the XAML), it appears as (obviously) "LEVEL1" or "LEVEL2" or "LEVEL3".

I'm interested in knowing how to display "LEVEL 1" (with a space) instead of displaying "LEVEL1".
The issue is that I can't define an identifier with a space or a number in the enum.

Is it possible that an enumerated is not the best way to implement what I want?

It seems to me a properly and orderly way to do it, but maybe it is not the right approach.

I have also considered creating a class for the priority levels but I am looking to solve it in a simpler way.

Comment: You can provide a helper function that converts the value into a description.  Or, you could apply a description attribute with the friendly name and use reflection to retrieve it that way.

Comment: Seems like a good place to use a converter. Code names should never appear directly on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is **When to use an enumerated in C#** and one way to look at this is asking whether assigning a human-readable alias for a value provides some kind of benefit (or not).

I see that that you have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61921873/5438626) your own question with a simple and elegant way to format the string based on `PLevel` after "changing the Priority property of the object to `int` type" (which makes sense) which solves your question as stated with regards to the *binding*:

> My problem is when I show that property in the interface (**with a binding in the XAML**), it appears as (obviously) "LEVEL1" or "LEVEL2" or "LEVEL3". I'm interested in knowing how to display "LEVEL 1" (with a space) instead of displaying "LEVEL1".

Alternatively, a xaml-friendly approach that *also* solves the question, works with either `int` or with `enum`, and provides more flexibility is to make an implementation of `IValueConverter` class and invoke it in the xaml as `Text="{Binding Path=PriorityLevel, Converter={StaticResource PriorityLevelConverter}}"`.

```
// Returns a formatted version of PriorityLevel.
// Works for EITHER int or enum
public class PriorityLevelToFormatted : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        => $"Level {(int)value}";
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unused");
}
```

---

One benefit of doing it this way is that you can convert the `PLevel` to *other* types using *different* criteria. So what if you make a converter that enables "Hyper" for levels higher than 1.

```
public class PriorityLevelToVisibility : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => (int)value == 1 ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unused");
}
```

[image: click response]

---

For [testing](https://github.com/IVSoftware/ivalueconverter-for-wpf-int-to-string-binding.git) this answer I used this minimal WPF form:

```
<iv:Window x:Class="wpf_window_ex.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_window_ex"
        xmlns:iv="clr-namespace:IVSoftware"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Main Window" Height="200" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PriorityLevelToFormatted x:Key="PriorityLevelConverter"/>
        <local:PriorityLevelToVisibility x:Key="PriorityLevelToHyper"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock 
            Visibility="{Binding Path=PLevel, Converter={StaticResource PriorityLevelToHyper}}"
            Text="Hyper Enabled"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Background="LightGreen"
            Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock 
            Name ="textLevel"
            Text="{Binding Path=PLevel, Converter={StaticResource PriorityLevelConverter}}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button
            Command="{Binding AdvancePriorityCommand}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Width="150"
            Grid.Row="3">
            <TextBlock>Advance Level</TextBlock>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</iv:Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with the Description Attribute and an extension method.

the enum would be:

```
public enum PriorityLevel 
{
    [Description("LEVEL 1")]
    LEVEL1 = 1,
    [Description("LEVEL 2")]
    LEVEL2 = 2,
    [Description("LEVEL 3")]
    LEVEL3 = 3
}
```

and the extension method I use quite a bit is

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T enumerationValue)
        where T : struct
    {
        var type = enumerationValue.GetType();
        if (!type.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(enumerationValue)} must be of Enum type", nameof(enumerationValue));
        }
        var memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumerationValue.ToString());
        if (memberInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            var attrs = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
            }
        }
        return enumerationValue.ToString();
    }
```

The extension method checks if the struct is an `enum` then using reflection looks for the `DescriptionAttribute` (when using an attribute on a class, property, enum value, etc. C# knows that the `Attribute` is unnecessary) and then returns the text.  If the enum does not have the `DescriptionAttribute` it returns the `ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

An enum is absolutely the right type to record this data - there are a finite number of possible values, with a defined order between them.

For your display issues, you can add a description to each enum value.

```
public enum PriorityLevel 
{
    [Description("LEVEL 1")]
    LEVEL1 = 1,
    [Description("LEVEL 2")]
    LEVEL2 = 2,
    [Description("LEVEL 3")]
    LEVEL3 = 3
}
```

A helper method can get the description for an enum value

```
public static class perEnumHelper
{
    public static string Description(this Enum value)
    {
        var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        var attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
            .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
            .ToList();
        return attributes.Any() 
            ? attributes.First().Description 
            : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarify me about if its correct or not use an enum in this case. So at the end of the day I must create another class to handle the description of the enum value. I was trying to avoid this and achieve it in a simpler way but it seems that there is not. Usually this should not take more than three lines in any language and should be extremly easy. The complexity of this approach to solve my problem makes me to think that probably this is not the right way to do it or raises doubts at least. I consider that is not worth code all those lines to get the desired behavior.

Comment: There is also another problem. After getting the description, the application should display that string on the interface, so if the property in XAML is bound, it must be of type string. That is not too representative of a Priority property as if it is of type PriorityLevel.

Comment: Like many things in WPF, extra code is required for the best results - but it's a write once (in a library) use many times activity. What I do is for each enum property that I know I'll want to display as text, I'll have a parallel property for the description that just returns the description of the enum value as a string. Also, for something like a ComboBox I have a class similar to a KeyValuePair - one element for the display and another for the value that I can use to set DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this getting the value of the enum item and changing the Priority property of the object to int type.

In code behind:

```
PLevel = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(PriorityLevel), PriorityLevel.LEVEL1.ToString());
```

In XAML:

```
Binding="{Binding PLevel, StringFormat={}LEVEL {0}}"
```